# tensorflow 2.5.0 has requirement h5py~=3.1.0, but you'll have h5py 3.3.0 which is incompatible

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, ubuntu, h5py

I am trying to install TensorFlow but getting these errors:

> ERROR: TensorFlow 2.5.0 has requirement h5py~=3.1.0, but you'll have h5py 3.3.0 which is incompatible.
> ERROR: tensorflow 2.5.0 has requirement numpy~=1.19.2, but you'll have numpy 1.21.0 which is incompatible.

I am installing it in Programming Environment with Python 3.8.5, pip 20.0.2, Ubuntu 20.04. How can I fix it?

Comment: I recommend creating a virtual environment. Create a base environment without h5py, create the virtual environment, then install with h5py 3.1.0 followed by TF 2.5.0. This is easy with the conda package manager. Otherwise you need to use the venv package.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @kcw78, create virtual environment and then install Tensorflow.

Tensorflow 2.5.0 requires h5py = 3.1.0.
Follow the instructions to create virtual environment and install tensorflow.

```
Set Up Anaconda Environments
conda create --name tf_env python=3

Activate the new Environment
source activate tf_env

Install Tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==2.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I find virtual environments annoying.  And I liked Conda at launch, but stopped because it went through a "death by slowness" period...

But, I couldn't install TensorFlow with my new 2021 M1 Pro, otherwise.
So, what worked is to use Apple's official instructions:
https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

Here they are, created below, for a pure command line solution (feel free to update):

*Make a virtual environment*

```
python3 -m venv ~/tensorflow-metal
source ~/tensorflow-metal/bin/activate
python -m pip install -U pip
```

*Download Conda and activate Conda environment, too*

```
curl -L https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh --output ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
chmod +x ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
sh ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
source ~/miniforge3/bin/activate
```

*Install TensorFlow dependencies via Conda*

```
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps==2.6.0
```

*Install base TensorFlow and patch for M1 processors*

```
python -m pip install tensorflow-macos
python -m pip install tensorflow-metal
```

Have a nice day.